# Put Canvas Inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to put a canvas inside of a ListBox using WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.  Just about anything is possible with WPF.  What do you mean specifically?

Sample Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="lbFoo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="300" Background="Orange">
   <Canvas Name="cnvFoo" Background="Green" Height="200" Width="200">
         <Label Name="lblFoo">This is a Label in a Canvas</Label>
   </Canvas>
</ListBox>
```